# Binary Matrix SQL

Tags: database, matrix, binary

I want to store a binary matrix into a database.

Matrix example:

```
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

Which is the best way to do that?

OBS: I don't understand much of db.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can store it as varchar(n^2). If you don't need to work on it in the DB, you can also store each line in the matrix as it's value- for example, your first line will be 77.

Answer (score 0):

or if you know the number of digits in any line and colomn you can save it in one decimal(11135377233198751900) or hexadecimal(9A88CE9888C8A09C) number